# SSRS radial gauge adding two values to scale

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

Hi I'm trying to improve my SSRS reports with new visualization and I'm trying to implement gauges. I have a particular dataset that looks at records that came into our system for the day and gets a percentage of which of those records ended up in error.

```
select num as success, num1 as error,  (cast(a.num1 as float)/cast(a.num as 
float))
from
(
select  (select COUNT(1) from myTable where status = 'SUCCESS' and 
CreateDate > GETDATE() - 1) as num , 
(select COUNT(1) from myTable where status= 'ERROR' and CreateDate> 
GETDATE() - 1) as num1
) a
```

What I'm trying to do is have a radial gauge where the scale has a max value of  of 'error' + 'success' in my query above. I'm also trying to show the 'error' value as a separate color on the same gauge. How can I achieve this look? Thanks.

my radial gauge

[image: my radial gauge]